# Get Join Keys dynamically from a table

Tags: oracle, execution-plan, impala

SQL/Impala

I have a scenario where I need to join my input file with a mapping table which has map columns and derived columns. The join keys are dynamic and need to taken from a dynamic metadata table.

Metadata table can be modified by user to either update or insert new keys. The join happens in multiple passes. Pass1 will have one set of columns as keys , Pass2 will have another set of columns as join keys.

Pass2 derived values can overwrite Pass1 derived values. The derived columns are same through out.

Example:

Keys metadata table

[image]

Mapping Table

[image]

In

Input File
[image]

Join keys for Pass1 are A,B,C,D,E. Join will map values 10,20,30,40,50 from Input file to Values 10,20,30,40,50 in mapping table - DerivedValues1,2,3,4 will be derived.

Join Keys for Pass2 are A,B,C,D - Join will map values 10,20,30,40 from Input File to values 10,20,30,40 in mapping table - DerivedValues1,2,3,4 will be derived and can overwrite values derived  in Pass1

In Pass3 - Column A and Derived Value3 will be join key. Join will map values 15, Jasmine to mapping table - DerivedValues1,2,3,4 will be derived.

Any idea how we could do this in SQL or Impala. Basically the platform is built in Big Data and we just need to write SQL like queries to implement this logic

Appreciate any help.

THanks
Nitin

Comment: *In Pass3 - Column A and Derived Value3 will be join key.* I see `Key1 = 'E'` for this row.

Comment: in SQL this will be a heap of CASEs or dynamic SQL.

Comment: Yes!! Its definitely too much code. Since its dynamic keys, not sure how a case would work